# Test iText Java application with Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, itext, junit4, bouncycastle

I developed a **JAVA** (JDK1.6) application to manage PDF file with **iText** (v5.5.0).
After I wrote test application using groovy, but when i create a **PdfReader** object, in my test case,

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("/my/path/project/test.pdf")
```

I obtain the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/cms/RecipientId
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2484)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.cms.RecipientId
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
```

The first asserts in groovy test class works fine. 
I created the same test class with JUnit4, and all works fine!

How can I fix the error in groovy test class?

I don't use **bouncycastle** class, why have I that ClassNotFound Exception?

**EDIT:**

**GroovyTestCase**

```
class PdfMergeItextTest extends GroovyTestCase {
    PdfMergeItext pdfMerge

    void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
        println "Test class [PdfMergeItext] avviato..."

        pdfMerge = new PdfMergeItext()
        pdfMerge.openOutputPdf("/my/path/project/output.pdf")
    }

    void tearDown() {
        println "Test class [PdfMergeItext] END."
    }

    @Test
    void testMergeSinglePdfFile() {
        println "Test one Pdf.."

        File outputPdf = new File("/my/path/project/output.pdf")
        assertTrue outputPdf.exists()
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("/my/path/project/test.pdf")
        pdfMerge.addPdf(pdfReader)
        pdfMerge.flush()
        pdfMerge.close()

        assert outputPdf.size() > 0

        println "File size: ${outputPdf.size()}"

        println "End test one Pdf"
    }
}
```

**JUnit4 TestCase**

```
public class PdfMergeItextUnitTest {
    PdfMergeItext pdfMergeItext = null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Start..");

        this.pdfMergeItext = new PdfMergeItext();
        this.pdfMergeItext.openOutputPdf("/my/path/project/output.pdf");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("END!");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMergePdfFile() throws IOException, BadPdfFormatException {
        File outputPdf = new File("/my/path/project/output.pdf");

        Assert.assertTrue(outputPdf.exists());

        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("/my/path/project/test.pdf");

        this.pdfMergeItext.addPdf(pdfReader);
        this.pdfMergeItext.flush();

        this.pdfMergeItext.close();

        Assert.assertTrue(outputPdf.size() > 0);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: it's not about creating the test. you have not specified your test classpath properly

Comment: @injecteer Why can you said that? My first asserts in groovy test class works fine, and the same test class with JUnit4 works fine!

Comment: I can only speculate, as I don't see any code here :)

Comment: `PdfReader` has a dependency on BouncyCastle. It needs BC for decrypting PDF files.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie ok, but why I have that exception only when I use GroovyTestCase?

Comment: I don't have a Crystal Ball. I don't know your configuration, not am I interested in seeing it. Just add the BC jars to your CLASSPATH and that should fix the problem.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I added BC jars to my classpath, but I have the same exception

Comment: Maybe you aren't using the correct version.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I speculate that iText already contains BC, because when I use it in JUnit, without include in my classpath BC, works fine.

Comment: If you are using an official iText version, it doesn't contain BC (I know, because I'm responsible for all iText releases). Maybe you already have BC in your CLASSPATH somewhere when using JUnit.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I use maven to import libraries. iText groupId is com.itextpdf and artifactId is itextpdf. I often used iText library and I never included BC in my classpath.

Comment: If you use the iText POM file, than you import BC as the BC libraries are listed as dependencies in the iText POM file. If you don't believe me, check the iText POM file ;-)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I believe you, but I don't understand why my itext java program works fine without to include BC library! Maybe maven resolve all dependencies automatically. For iText 5.5.0 which version of BC library i should use?

Comment: Maven indeed resolves dependencies automatically, that's why people use Maven. You can find the jars and versions needed in the POM:
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.49</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.49</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>`

Comment: @BrunoLowagie When I building and running my JAR file works fine and also when I test with JUnit4, instead when I running test with groovy it doesn't work! Maybe is a compatibility problem between maven and groovy. Thanks :-) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BounceCastle JARs are optional, see the [`pom.xml`](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itext/code/trunk/itext/pom.xml) (search for dependency). So, if you didn't include them in your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` , you won't get them (anyway, what build tool are you using)?

So if you are using dependency management I understand why it is not there. The real question is: why is it needed in the first test and not in the second test?

- Please make the tests totally equalent (you are calling `addPdf` once vs. twice and you are calling `length` vs. `size`
- Since BounceCastle is used for decryption, are you testing with the same PDF file?

Comment: Now my tests are equivalent, but it doesn't important because the exception was thrown before, when I created the PdfReader Object. I test the same PDF and the PDF file is not encrypted. I use Maven in IntelliJ IDEA project, I don't use any external tool to build.

Comment: I took your code and tested it. Both test (JUnit and Groovy) fails with the same error: BouncyCastle is missing. I noticed also that you use GroovyTestCase which is for JUnit3 and Annotation @Test which is for JUnit4, so you mix both versions. If you want I can post my code. Since I have not your class under test this might be the reason for the failure.

Comment: I've rewrite my groovy test case, and now it works fine. I don't know why the previous class doesn't work. In my project Maven resolve all the dependencies, also BouncyCastle library.